# How to pass date to breeze

Tags: datetime, breeze

I am passing date to query in breeze as below

```
 Predicate.create('approvedOn', op.GreaterThanOrEqual, "01.05.1985");
```

But i get invalid date error. How to pass date to breeze query?

**Update1**

I also tried passing date by converting it to ISO 8601 format but still get error

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a javascript date object in your query.

```
var aDate = new Date(1985, 5, 1, 0, 0, 0)
Predicate.create('approvedOn', op.GreaterThanOrEqual, aDate);
```

Comment: Now i dont get any error but when i pass date var aDate= (2014, 1, 7, 0, 0, 0) then in  debug mode i check value of aDate and it shows Fri Feb 7 00:00:00 UTC+0100 2014. Why does it show as Feb instead of January?

Comment: The javascript Date ctor assumes that months start with 0.  See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

Answer (score -1):

Do you try to convert it to other formats?

I worked with some projects that use query with date like this:

```
var time = new Date($.now());
var pre = new breeze.Predicate.create("DatePost", ">=", time);
```

It works fine. You should try with other date format, if get errors, post them here.

Comment: I think you get error becasue "01.05.1985" is not valid format, maybe it should be 01/05/1985 ?